# fix position of table's first 2 column using css

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically generated table, table column's may have large number so that user need to scroll horizontally to see all column's data. My task is that, I have to make fixed first 2 column when user want to see other column's data.

[image]

Till now, I can make absolute position of first 2 column, but others column is not properly positioned. My last output is given below:
[image]

My code is given below:

**HTML**

```
<table id="teamTable" class="table data-table table-hover" ts-wrapper>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th class="table-col-xs table-col-border" rowspan="2">
              <input type="checkbox">
           </th>
           <th class="table-col-border" ts-default rowspan="2">
                Name
           </th>
           <th ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center table-th-removable">
               column 3
           </th>
           <th ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center table-th-removable">
               column 4
           </th>
           ................................   
      </tr>
       <tr>
           <th ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center">
              column 3
           </th>
           <th ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center">
              column 4
           </th>
            ..............................
       </tr>
    </thead>

     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="" ts-repeat>
          <td class="table-col-xs table-col-border" rowspan="2">
              <input type="checkbox">
           </td>
           <td class="table-col-border" ts-default rowspan="2">
                User  Name
           </td>
           <td ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center table-th-removable">
               column 3
           </td>
           <td ng-repeat="" class="table-col-sm table-col-border text-center table-th-removable">
               column 4
           </td>
           ................................   
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**CSS**

```
/* first make some space using 'margin-left' */
table#teamTable {
   margin-left: 125px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* first table heading */
table#teamTable > thead > tr:first-child > th:nth-child(1) {
   margin-left: -126px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 45%;
} 

/* second table heading */
table#teamTable > thead > tr:first-child  > th:nth-child(2) {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -76px;
   z-index: 9999;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 45%;
   width: 75px;
} 

/* rest of the table heading */ 
table#teamTable > thead > tr:first-child  > th:nth-child(n+3) {
   position: relative;
} 

table#teamTable > thead > tr:first-child  > th  {
   position: relative;
} 

/* first table column */
table#teamTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -126px;
   z-index: 9999;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 50px;
} 

 /* second table column */
table#teamTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -76px;
   width: 75px;
   z-index: 9999;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 50px;
} 

/* rest of the table column */
table#teamTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n + 3) {
   position: relative; 
}
```

[plnkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wr40zvPF8bk8EdNxxE39?p=preview)

Comment: Please provide more of the original/sample code. I'd like to recreate the issue in its entirety to help you in the best manner possible. This is missing much of the styling that I feel will not only help me *visually* see the issue at hand, but also ensure that nothing unexpected interferes with the results I provide.

Comment: your sample code does not provide a working sample. please provide the rest of your code https://plnkr.co/edit/fV6Ui4yoiHXXaCYM5ugv?p=preview

Comment: @MassDebates  https://plnkr.co/edit/Wr40zvPF8bk8EdNxxE39?p=preview

Comment: @KCCoder https://plnkr.co/edit/Wr40zvPF8bk8EdNxxE39?p=preview

Comment: You could achieve this by observing scroll event. if offset is higher than 0 copy the first two cols and put them absolute in front. hide the cols inside the table and add left padding in the two cols width. if offset is smaller than two cols width hide the fixed copy and make all tables cols visible again.

Comment: I looked at the code; it's still hard to determine which cells are the ones you've identified in your diagrams. **In the future, please consider putting in placeholder content instead of blacking out everything.** From what I can see, you can take advantage of Simon Kraus's idea, or you can create an extra column (redundant) to act as an exact, relatively positioned copy of the fixed/absolute positioned cells at the left hand side. That way you can off-set the cells while still maintaining a fixed 1st column

Answer (score 1):

Style the tbody with predefined size and use overflow-y: scroll;

Check this fiddle and logic `http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/bo8bu0u3/1/`

Also you can use table header fixed using fixedheadertable

```
  http://www.fixedheadertable.com/
```

Another example of fixed `http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/KHdih`